# Is Stream.count() guranteed to visit each element?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In other words, is the following line guranteed to print `num` lines?

```
int num = list.stream().peek(System.out::println).count();
```

This question was triggered by a discussion in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41346586/2513200

I vaguely remember a discussion that optimizations that avoid iteration might be legal, but didn't find anything conclusive during a quick search.

The [JavaDocs for Stream.count](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) contain this statement:

> This is a special case of a reduction and is equivalent to:
>       `return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();`

but I'm not sure whether this provides any guarantees if the stream can somehow determine the result in a short-circuiting way.

Comment: It will be modified in Java 9 (see the API Note): http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--

Comment: The _result_ is requivalent, it's not guaranteed to execute anything.

Comment: Just after that part of the documentation, you will find: "An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline [...] if it is capable of computing the count directly from the stream source. In such cases no source elements will be traversed and no intermediate operations will be evaluated."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope, it's not. It will not do it in Java 9 due to optimized `count()` implementation (if stream size is known in advance, it will skip iteration).

See [JDK-8067969](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067969) for more details. The documentation in [JDK-9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) was updated accordingly:

> An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline (either sequentially or in parallel) if it is capable of computing the count directly from the stream source. In such cases no source elements will be traversed and no intermediate operations will be evaluated. Behavioral parameters with side-effects, which are strongly discouraged except for harmless cases such as debugging, may be affected.

Comment: Most likely the iteration will be skipped when the backing spliterator is SIZED.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard, to be more precise if the last stream has SIZED StreamOpFlag. StreamOpFlags are similar to spliterator characteristics, but somewhat different. If you have intermediate operations, you don't have a spliterator for them, but you have StreamOpFlags. With intermediate `map()` or `peek()` you're fine, but intermediate `filter()` or `distinct()` will clear the SIZED.