# Extract multiple values from a single Java stream

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

I've to extract two values ( min & max ) from a `List` of my custom objects, and currently I am creating streams twice and extracting it separately. I think it might be optimization to use a single stream and use the map or similar function to get both min and max in a single stream. Is that feasible?

```
public class MyClass {

    public static class MyC {
        double val;
        public MyC(double val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public double getVal() {return val;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<MyC> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new MyC(10.0d));
        list.add(new MyC(20.0d));

        double min = Optional.ofNullable(list).stream()
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .limit(13)
                        .map(MyC::getVal)
                        .min(Double::compare)
                        .orElse(getMinDefault());

        double max = Optional.ofNullable(list).stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .limit(13)
                .map(MyC::getVal)
                .max(Double::compare)
                .orElse(getMaxDefault());

    }

    private static double getMinDefault() {
        return 1.0d;
    }

    private static double getMaxDefault() {
        return 20.0d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Had i known how to, i would not have posted here :)

Comment: You should sort the list and take first and last value rather than running the stream twice.

Comment: @SujayMohan I do not want to sort the list, as the list would change which i do not want, also the list could be very big.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816264/concise-way-to-get-both-min-and-max-value-of-java-8-stream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concise way to get both min and max value of Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816264/concise-way-to-get-both-min-and-max-value-of-java-8-stream)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) for both the `max` and `min` of your value attribute.

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = list // avoid initialising list as 'null'
        .stream()
        .limit(13)
        .mapToDouble(MyC::getVal)
        .summaryStatistics();
double max = summaryStatistics.getMax();
double min = summaryStatistics.getMin();
```

Regarding the custom default values to fall back upon, you can use conditional logic such as :

```
double max = getMaxDefault();
double min = getMinDefault();
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    DoubleSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = list
            .stream()
            .limit(13)
            .mapToDouble(MyC::getVal)
            .summaryStatistics();

    max = summaryStatistics.getMax();
    min = summaryStatistics.getMin();
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but if you see my response, `orElse` has different defaults for max and min, how can i do similar here?

Comment: @NoviceUser updated in the answer, it would be better handled as a conditional branch rather than the use of `Optional` here.